# Gradle with Lombok breaks randomly

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I just found the strangest issue.

For the last weeks I've being working on certain project. From start I was using gradle as build tool and some lombok annotations.

This morning the build broke, the error being the lombok code is not injected.

With the help of git bisect I found a particular commit from yesterday which worked fine. Looking at the diff, there was no changes on any configuration files.

Now, when I switch to the a newer commit I can build the project (with all my new changes) with no issue, but if I clean the project, the problem is there again.

Summarizing

1. If I remove the build directory and then build the project, it breaks because lombok-injected code is missing.
2. If I checkout some particular commit and then build, everything is fine when I *return* to the newest point and rebuild the project.

This is my build.gradle.kts file

```
plugins {
    java
    id("io.freefair.lombok") version "5.1.0"
}

group = "example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter", "junit-jupiter-api", "5.6.2")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter", "junit-jupiter-engine", "5.6.2")
    testImplementation("org.assertj", "assertj-core", "3.15.0")
}


configure<JavaPluginConvention> {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                "Main-Class" to "my.main.Class"
        )
    }
}
```

As you can see I don't even have runtime dependencies (that's a requirement, the jar must be totally independent).

Truth be told, I can live with this weird fix of jumping back and forward on my commits, but the fact that it's happening and I don't know why is killing me.

Comment: Are you running this via the terminal?  Or with an IDE's integration?

Comment: From the command line. If it's helpful, my OS is ArchLinux

Comment: "the plugin runs a delombok before compiling" - No, the plugin just adds a `delombok` task that is used for the `javadoc` task. Compilation uses the actual sources and the Lombok annotation processor. What Lombok annotations do you use and how does your configuration file look like? Also, what annotation do not seem to work (if not all)?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've updated the question.

Comment: "generated" is still the right term, it ist just the difference between being generated by the build tool (or its plugin) and being generated by the compiler. Could you edit your post regarding my additional questions?

Comment: Why do you have junit and assertj on your runtime classpath? These should be on the test classpath only (unless you are writing a test library)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try using vanilla lombok without the plugin. Eg

```
ext {
    versions = [lombok: '1.18.12'] 
} 
dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:$versions.lombok"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$versions.lombok"

    testCompileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:$versions.lombok"
    testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$versions.lombok"
}
```

https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle